# Refresh React app, get nginx 404 error on Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, nginx, http-status-code-404

Alright so every time I refresh my React app on a page that isn't the root/home page I get a 404 error. I've already done a lot of digging and found that I'm supposed to change my nginx config file. The only issue is this change that's working for everyone else is doing absolutely nothing for me.

File path - /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

My nginx config file looks like this -

```
location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
```

I've even tried adding a root directory at /var/www/html; To no surprise it didn't work.

Based off everything I've seen this SHOULD work... so why isn't it? Is this now a React Router issue or something? Any help would be greatly appreciate, I'm beyond stumped with this issue. If more information is needed I can gladly provide it, I'm sure not sure what else could be the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of messing around with the nginx.config I finally solved my issue.

Directory - /etc/nginx/sites-available | then - sudo nano default

What worked for me -

```
# Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.html;
        }
```

My root is still set to - root /var/www/html

For anyone having troubles try completely purging all nginx files and reinstalling for a clean slate. What I think was wrong for mine was I had added to the "nginx.conf" file and that ended up causing complications with the other config file "default." So all in all, only touch the default config file, and leave nginx.conf as default.